# How to use one model for multiple tables in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

I am looking for solutions, but can't really understand. I'm new in Laravel and I want a simple instruction on how to use one model for multiple tables like CodeIgniter as follows:

Controller myController:

```
public function shipBuilding()
{
    $data = $this->input->post();

    $response = $this->MyModel->shipbuildingSave($data);

}

public function contact()
{
    $data = $this->input->post();

    $response = $this->MyModel->contactSave($data);

}
```

Model MyModel:

```
public function shipbuildingSave($data){
    $this->db->insert('tbl_shipbuilding', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function contactSave($data){
    $this->db->insert('tbl_contact', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: I dont see u using multiple table in ur codeigniter model ??

Comment: @Jigs1212 I have updated now you can see the code again

Comment: i still dont see multiple table

Comment: @Jigs1212 The different table is being called from myModel, for example, tbl_shipbuilding and tbl_contact using save method

Comment: That's not possible in laravel. Model should have only one table.

Comment: In Laravel you can define the relationship between models (tables). Then in the controller you can edit the related tables. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships and https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how models work in Laravel. each model should be a representation of one single table.

You could, however, change the table name on booting the model up:

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'example';

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new AgeScope);

        // Set the $this->table depending on some logic.
    }
}
```

But again, this is probably not recommended for your case.